# Remainder on Float in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, modulo

I just want to show you the results of the operations in python. I cannot explain.

```
>>> 1.0%1.0
0.0  (OK)
>>> 1.0%0.1
0.09999.... 
>>> 1.0%0.001
0.00999....
>>> 1.0 %0.0001
0.000999...
```

... and so on. I need something that allows me to understand whether the remainder of 'x%y' is 0.0, namely 'y' divides 'x' exactly N times, where N is an integer.
Due to the previous behavior I don't know how to set a possible tolerance to determine if the remainder is next to 0.
Any help?

Comment: Short: Use the `decimal` module. Long: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [this (long) response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats) says, use `decimal` module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('3.5') % Decimal('0.1')
Decimal('0.0')
>>> print(Decimal('3.5') % Decimal('0.1'))
0.0
>>> (Decimal(7)/2) % (Decimal(1)/10)
Decimal('0.0')
```

The problem is essentially due to the representation of floats in the system, you can read stuff about that everywhere on the Internet, and in the response linked.