# Modulo in sage returning a negative value

Tags: python, sage

I am new to SAGE and am having a problem with something very simple. I have the following code:

```
delay = float(3.5)
D = delay%1.0
D
```

But this returns the value `-0.5` instead of the expected `0.5`. What am I doing wrong?

If I change delay to be `delay = float(2.5)`, I get the right answer, so I don't know why it isn't consistent (I am sure I am using the modulo wrong somehow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats) will answer things very well indeed for you.

However, I don't know why you are using `float` in Sage.  Then you could just use Python straight up.  Anyway, the `%` operator is tricky to use outside of integers.  For example, here is the docstring for its use on Sage rational numbers.

```
   Return the remainder of division of self by other, where other is
   coerced to an integer

   INPUT:

   * ``other`` - object that coerces to an integer.

   OUTPUT: integer

   EXAMPLES:

      sage: (-4/17).__mod__(3/1)
      1
```

I assume this is considered to be a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thank you, that was good reading and did explain it. Since I am just trying to get the decimal portion of the value, I changed that section of code to be `D = float(str(delay-int(delay))[1:])`. Also, I was typecasting as floats as an attempt to make modulo work, I have since removed them.