# Why is using a generator function twice as fast in this case?

Tags: python, performance, generator

## The code which is common for both the implementations:

```
from math import sqrt

def factors(x):
    num = 2
    sq = int(sqrt(x))
    for i in range(2, sq):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            num += 2
    return num + ((1 if sq == sqrt(x) else 2) if x % sq == 0 else 0)
```

## 1. Implementation which doesn't make use of a generator function:

```
i = 1
while True:
    if factors(i * (i+1) * 0.5) > 500:
        print(int(i * (i+1) * 0.5))
        break
    i += 1
```

## 2. Implementation which makes use of a generator function:

```
def triangle():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield int(0.5 * i * (i + 1))
        i += 1

t = triangle()

while True:
    num = t.__next__()
    if factors(num) > 500:
        print(num)
        break
```

## The Question:

The first implementation takes about 4 seconds while the second one takes approximately 8.2 seconds. Why is there such a big difference between the run times of the two implementations?

Comment: Does it matter that it's a generator function, or is this just another case of [Python code is faster when you put it in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function)?

Comment: *The first implementation takes about 4 seconds while the second one takes approximately 8.2 seconds* - so is your post title correct, or are the order of your code blocks correct?

Comment: The implementation with generator is faster and takes around 4 seconds

Comment: @SaratAdusumilli: My question isn't about which implementation makes conceptual sense.  If you take your first implementation and put the whole `while True` thing into a function, is it faster?  If so, the difference doesn't have to do with using a generator function, but just with using a function, as described in the post I linked to.

Comment: @BrenBarn I believe the only (good) way to write the above program using a function instead of a generator function would be by making use of a variable defined in the module. This would run slower than the one with a generator function. A generator function is perfect for this program. I don't think there would be much of a difference when you put the code in a function. (The difference is in milliseconds in the question you linked to.)

Comment: @SaratAdusumilli: No, the difference between function and non-function versions in that question is a few seconds.

Comment: @BrenBarn It was in milliseconds. 0m denotes millisecond.

Answer (score 11):

temp1():

```
def temp1():
        i = 1
        while True:
            if factors(i * (i+1) * 0.5) > 500:
                print(int(i * (i+1) * 0.5))
                break
            i += 1
```

temp2():

```
def temp2():
    def triangle():
        i = 1
        while True:
            yield int(0.5 * i * (i + 1))
            i += 1

    t = triangle()

    while True:
        num = t.next()
        if factors(num) > 500:
            print(num)
            break
```

cProfile for both:

[image]
After changing the `factors` call in `temp1()` to `factors(int(...))`, It turns out that `temp1()` takes the similar time

`Modified temp1 to pass int rather than float:`

```
def temp1():
    i = 1
    while True:
        if factors(int(i * (i+1) * 0.5)) > 500:
            print(int(i * (i+1) * 0.5))
            break
        i += 1
```

[image]

So it turns out that in your first implementation you are passing `float` to the `factors()` and floating point arithmetic is complex than integer arithmetic

**Why Floating point operations are complex??**

Because the way floats are represented internally is different from ints, they are represented in 3 parts as sign , mantissa and exponent (IEEE 754) whereas representation of integer is much simple and so are operations like addition and subtraction on integers, even multiplication and division are performed using a combination of addition,subtraction and shift operations internally . since integer addition and subtraction are simple, so are their division/multiplications and hence floating point operations are some what expensive

**Why Floating point modulo is expensive than Integer?**

The answer is same as above , A modulo operation is nothing but combination of primitive operations mentioned above as follows:

```
a mod n = a - (n*int(a/n))
```

Since primitive operations for floats are more expensive, so is modulo for floats

Comment: Why is the modulo operation more expensive on float than on int?

Comment: @SaratAdusumilli , I've updated the answer stating why modulo operation on float is more expensive , check it out :)

Answer (score 8):

In the explicit case you're not taking the `int` of the expression before calling `factors` and therefore the value passed will be a floating-point number.

In the generator case you're instead yielding `int(...)`, calling `factors` passing an integer number.

Comment: Timed it, removing the cast from the generator makes the two implementations run in almost identical time.

Comment: @6502 - it would be great if you could explain why operations on float are more expensive from operations on int.

Comment: @SaratAdusumilli it's most likely the modulo operation that occurs inside the loop and not the sqrt that is taking most of the extra time in the case of floats

Comment: @samgak You are right it is actually the modulo operation on float which is more expensive. But when it comes the sqrt float is actually faster than the int.

Comment: @6502 Why is the modulo operation more expensive on float than on int?

Comment: @SaratAdusumilli: In Python the modulo operator on floats provides a functionality that is not present in C. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14763891/320726

Answer (score 3):

You can remove factors() of the code, make *500* much larger.

```
# implementation 1
i = 1
while True:
    if (i * (i + 1) * 0.5) > n: # n=100000
        # print int(i * (i + 1) * 0.5),
        break
    i += 1
```

and *%timeit*, to compare with implementation 2:

```
def triangle():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i * (i + 1) * 0.5
        i += 1

t = triangle()

while True:
    num = t.next()
    if num > n:
        # print num,
        break
```

Comment: I don't think the generator function is what really matter

Answer (score 2):

The only difference as far as I know is that you do the calculation `i * (i+1) * 0.5` twice in the first example. It is not a expensive computation, but it might make a big difference since it is such a big portion of the program..

Comment: The calculation occurs twice only in one case and it doesn't make much of a difference to the performance.

Comment: True, I did not realize that there was a break there. And I did not take a close enough look at factors. My bad.