# How to avoid modulus floating point error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, modulus

I'm using the modulus operator and I'm get some floating point errors. For example,

```
>>> 7.2%3
1.2000000000000002
```

Is my only recourse to handle this by using the `round` function? E.g.

```
>>> round(7.2%3, 1)
1.2
```

I don't a priori know the number of digits I'm going to need to round to, so I'm wondering if there's a better solution?

Comment: Consider using `decimal.Decimal`?

Comment: Floating-point numbers do not represent exact values.  You introduced inaccuracy into your program the moment you wrote ``7.2``.  If your program can't live with a trillionth of a percent error, you need to use a decimal or rational data type.

Comment: I think this has been answered here. Because Math is weird.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want arbitrary precision, use the `decimal` module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal('7.2') % decimal.Decimal('3')
Decimal('1.2')
```

Please [read the documentation carefully](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html).

Notice I used a `str` as an argument to `Decimal`. Look what happens if I didn't:

```
>>> decimal.Decimal(7.2) % decimal.Decimal(3)
Decimal('1.200000000000000177635683940')
>>>
```

Comment: So I need to make sure I `str()` the numbers before passing them to `Decimal`. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @wogsland I would be careful with `str`, which automatically rounds, but floating point errors can creep into the rounding. Use string literals where possible.