# Issue with Python modulo

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def height(cent):
    height= {}
    height["feet"]= int(cent/30.48)
    height["inch"]= int(cent%30.48)/2.54
    print (height)
height (182.88)
print (182.88/30.48)
print (182.88%30.48)
```

The output is: 
{'inch': 11, 'feet': 6}

6.0

30.479999999999993

Why does 182.88%30.48 not equal zero?

Comment: Why are you expecting it to be? `182.88 / 30.48` is 6.033, not 6 exactly.

Comment: [Similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats)

Comment: Do as little floating-point math as possible. Compute `h = int(cent / 2.54)`, then use integer arithmetic  to compute `feet, inches = divmod(h, 12)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of 30.48 is really 30.4799.. This is because of the way that [floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) are stored in python. So when you are dividing 30.479999 by 182.88, the resulting rounded integer is 5 (i.e. `182.88 // 30.48 == 5`). So the remainder is 30.47999...