# Python modulo between logarithm

Tags: python

I'm trying to check in Python if a math.log(x, base) has decimal or not:

```
import math

# math.log(8, 2) = 3
print math.log(8)
print math.log(2)
print math.log(8) / math.log(2)
print 2.07944154168 % 0.69314718056
print math.log(8) % math.log(2)
```

Output is:

```
2.07944154168
0.69314718056
3.0
0.0
0.69314718056
```

Why does fourth print row return zero but fifth does not?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats

Comment: did you notice that % returns the same value of 0.69314718056, which is the second operator ??? a % b = b ... lol

Comment: @mlwn Yes I did, but I don't know what to think about.

Comment: @RayToal Helps to understand something, but how then can I check if log(x, base) gives result without decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be closed for being a duplicate, but just so one can see how this plays out:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(8)
2.0794415416798357
>>> math.log(2)
0.6931471805599453
```

Now let's say you need to compute `math.log(8) % math.log(2)`. You need to compute the remainder after dividing `math.log(2)` into `math.log(8)`. Let's see, does it go in 3 times?

```
  0.6931471805599453
+ 0.6931471805599453
+ 0.6931471805599453
--------------------
  2.0794415416798359
```

Woah! We overshot the value of 2.0794415416798357 which means it actually goes in TWO times:

```
  0.6931471805599453
+ 0.6931471805599453
--------------------
  1.3862943611198906
```

Okay so what is the remainder?

```
  2.0794415416798359
- 1.3862943611198906
--------------------
  0.6931471805599453
```

So TL;DR your remainder is close to `math.log(2)` because of rounding errors. It does not go in exactly three times. It goes in two times with just about `math.log(2)` left over.

Yes when you print the quotient it says `3.0` but again, this is all rounding error in floating point, which is not unique to Python.

Comment: I understand what happens now. Maybe I should read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to go deeper as suggested in the [python module question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats). What do you mean with TL;DR?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get using python 3

```
>>> print (math.log(8))
2.0794415416798357
>>> print (math.log(2))
0.6931471805599453
>>> print (math.log(8) / math.log(2))
3.0
>>> print (2.07944154168 % 0.69314718056)
0.0
>>> print (math.log(8) % math.log(2))
0.6931471805599452
>>> print (2.0794415416798357 % 0.6931471805599453)
0.6931471805599452
```

It looks like in your example (python 2 ?), the precision of math.log is not enough.

Comment: Yes, I was trying in Tutorialspoint, with Python 2.7