# Why is the modulo returning an incorrect value

Tags: python, python-2.7, modulo

I have this modulo equation that I believe should return 0 as .01 goes into 1 10 times evenly. Why does it yield `.01`?

```
print 1 % .01
```

Comment: It doesn't. It yields 0.00999999999999997939148510539553171838633716106414794921875. And `print` just tries to be helpful by not showing something that ugly.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I'm confused though. Why does .01 not go into 1 10 times evenly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1672429

Comment: For a more detailed answer see [Python modulo on floats][1]. The gist is that programming languages don't store floats as decimals. This is because of binary representation of floating points.

Example: try `format(0.01, '.30f')` and you'll see `'0.010000000000000000208166817117'`

Therefore, when you divide 1 by this number slightly above 0.01, you get 99 + remainder a number very close to 0.01.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats

Comment: In brief, there is no binary floating point value that is exactly .01, so Python converts the float literal '.01' to closest one.  If you want exact decimal values, use the `decimal` module.

Comment: I didn't like the explanation in the highly rated answer, so I tried to make it explain it in simple maths above. I hope it helps someone!

Comment: To expand my comment about using decimal.Decimal: after `from decimal import Decimal as d`, `d('1') % d('.01')` has the 'expected' value `Decimal('0.00')`.  If the question had been "How do I get the 'correct' value 0", this would have been the answer.