# module python shows a wrong answer (floats module)

Tags: python-3.x

couldn't fine answer here.
my code:

```
t = 0
i = 0
arrival = 7.2
while t < 3600:
    time_passed = 0.1
    if t % arrival == 0:
         i+=1
    t+= time_passed
print (i)
```

===> I get 1 for some reason. can't understand how to fix it (it should be 500)
edit: I want to know how to change my code in order to fix the issue, not the theory behind..

Comment: cause 3600/7.2 = 500

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I still don't see what to change in my code to fix that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of floating point rounding issues. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats) post on why it happens.

If you want a quick fix, just use pythons decimal library.

```
from decimal import Decimal
t = 0
i = 0
arrival = Decimal('7.2')
while t < 3600:
    time_passed = Decimal('0.1')
    if t % arrival == 0:
         i+=1
    t+= time_passed
print (i)
```