# Python modulo on np array

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, modulo

Another question, [Python modulo on floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats/), describes why Python's modulo has trouble with floats (I also understand that computer numbers are not *numbers* as covered in this [essay](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), especially multiples of 3). However, I am having a similar, but different problem with modulo and the accepted answer does not work.

Here is a reproducible example in Python 3.7.1 on a MacBook Pro:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([2.012, 2.012 *2, 2.012 *3, 2.012 *4, 2.012 *5, 2.012 *6])
x % 2.012
# array([0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 2.0120000e+00, 0.0000000e+00,
#        4.4408921e-16, 2.0120000e+00])
```

If I try the accepted answer, I still get the same problem:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(3*2.012) % Decimal(2.012)
# Decimal('2.011999999999999566568931186')
```

My specific question: **How do I calculate the modulo and get zero for series such as my example?**

**Edited based upon feedback:**

As a specific example, how do I do the modulo operator if my data looks like this (the specific values will be read in from actual data):

```
## X is read in from real data
x = np.array([2.012, 4.024, 6.036, 8.048, 1, 2, 3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 5, 6, 2.012, 2.012, 2.012])
[D(x) % D(frequency) for x in detections]
#[Decimal('0E-51'), Decimal('0E-51'), Decimal('2.011999999999999566568931186'), Decimal('0E-51'), Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000000'), Decimal('2.000000000000000000000000000'), Decimal('0.9879999999999999893418589636'), Decimal('1.199999999999999955591079015'), Decimal('1.300000000000000044408920985'), Decimal('1.399999999999999911182158030'), Decimal('1.000000000000000000000000000'), Decimal('0.9759999999999999786837179272'), Decimal('1.975999999999999978683717927'), Decimal('0E-51'), Decimal('0E-51'), Decimal('0E-51')]
```

Comment: Are the intial values provided as floating numbers or just as text in the actual data? You need to consider converting the values to decimals from the very beginning.

Comment: They'll be read in with Pandas or numpy. I haven't gotten to that part of the code yet.

Comment: I don't think either of them has decimals as a built-in data type. In that case you might need to consider either (1) using an integer representation, e.g. by multiplying the values with 1000; or (2) keeping the floating number representation and round the modulo results.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [6]: from decimal import Decimal as D
In [7]: D('3')*D('2.012') % D('2.012')
Out[7]: Decimal('0.000')
```

Python evaluates arguments before passing them to functions (or callables such as `Decimal`). So you must avoid evaluating the *float* `3*2.012` if you want to preserve the decimal value. For this reason, always pass string representations of decimals to `Decimal` rather than floats.

---

If you have a text file containing

```
2.012, 4.024, 6.036, 8.048, 1, 2, 3, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1, 5, 6, 2.012, 2.012, 2.012
```

then load the values *as strings* and the convert them to `Decimal` so as to avoid ever representing them as floats.

```
import csv
from decimal import Decimal as D
freq = D('2.012')
with open('data', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    X = [D(item) for item in next(reader)]
    print([xi % freq for xi in X])
```

yields

```
[Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('1.000'), Decimal('2.000'), Decimal('0.988'), Decimal('1.200'), Decimal('1.300'), Decimal('1.400'), Decimal('1.000'), Decimal('0.976'), Decimal('1.976'), Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('0.000'), Decimal('0.000')]
```

Since Decimals are not a NumPy/Pandas native dtype, storing them in a NumPy
arrays or Pandas Series would require the generic `object` dtype. NumPy/Pandas
does not offer any vectorized operations for Decimals, so there would be no
performance gain by using NumPy/Pandas here.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helps me understand my problem better. I'm about to edit my question based upon your answer