# Strange Python 3 mod behavior for longs

Tags: python-3.x, math, integer, long-integer

Consider this code snippet.

```
>>> n, m = 10011617, 100000000000006340
>>> s = lambda n: n * (n + 1) / 2
>>> s(n)
50116242483153.0
>>> s(n) == int(s(n))
True
>>> m % s(n)
18096246116101.0
>>> m % int(s(n))
18096246116105
```

As you can see, `s(n)` is an integer (mathematically), yet `m % s(n) != m % int(s(n))`.

Could this have to do with `s(n)` or `m` being a long under the hood? Even if that's the case, why does `s(n) == int(s(n))` yet when I take the modulus the results are not equal?

*P.S. I ran this in repl.it*

Comment: Use integer division `n * (n + 1) / /2` rather than `n * (n + 1) / 2`. Floats have limited precision.

Comment: Actually -- it isn't the same. For larger `n`, `(n+1)//2` might differ from `int((n+1)/2)`.

Comment: @JohnColeman I see. Why then does python return True for `s(n) == int(s(n))` but returns different results when I take the modulus?

Comment: Because of how `==` is implemented when applied between a float and an int.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but see: [Python modulo on floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14763722/4996248) since this is the operator that you are using in `%s(n)`

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case the problem is due more to `m` than `s(n)`. When computing `m % s(n)`, since `s(n)` is a float, `m` is coerced to a float. But -- `float(m)` loses precision. The clearest way to see this is that

```
m == 100000000000006340
```

but

```
int(float(m)) == 100000000000006336
```

Note that `100000000000006336 % 50116242483153 == 18096246116101`, which shows where the mystery value comes from.