# Rounding in Python to avoid machine precision errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, precision

I would like to check if a float is a multiple of another float, but am running into issues with machine precision. For example:

```
t1 = 0.02
factor = 0.01
print(t1%factor==0)
```

The above outputs `True`, but

```
t2 = 0.030000000000000002
print(round(t2,5)%factor==0)
```

This outputs `False`. At some points in my code the number I am checking develops these machine precision errors, and I thought I could fix the issue simply by rounding it (I need 5 decimal places for later in my code, but it also doesn't work if I just round it to 2 decimal places).

Any ideas why the above check `round(t2,5)%factor==0` doesn't work as expected, and how I can fix it?

Comment: For me, t1%factor == 0 returns false

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle Sorry, I meant to type t1=0.02 (see edit), which returns True. But this uncovers something very weird. Why would 0.02%0.01==0 return True, while 0.03%0.01==0 return False?

Comment: I think since `round(t2,5)%factor` and `t1%factor` will return a floating point number so you need to round it also to `round(round(t2,5)%factor)` and `round(t1%factor)`

Comment: @user696969 's answer can also be correct, however, it will not work if the difference is 0.4999, which should return False, but if you round it, it will return True.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: This is an excellent explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763891/3047101

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python modulo on floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763722/python-modulo-on-floats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, floats in Python are... messed up, for the lack of a better word. And they can act in very unexpected ways. (You can read more about that behaviour [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).)

For your goal however, a better way is this:

```
t2 = 0.03000003
factor = 0.01
precision = 10000  # 4 digits
print(int(t2*precision)%int(factor*precision)==0)
```

Moving the maths to an integer-based calculation solves most of those issues.

Comment: It's not really Python's fault though.  It's just following IEEE specifications for float arithmetic by delegating to hardware (is my understanding of how it works).

Comment: I am not disagreeing that it is not, but it is a fact that floats do not act the way most people expect them to, in other languages, especially for people who have not experienced the issue before (Similar to the way parameters work in functions e.g. `def myfunc(newList =[])`.) It is not an unintended behaviour, but it is a common "gotcha!". @KyleParsons But perhaps I could've used better wording.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle: It has absolutely nothing to do with Python. JavaScript, C, C++, C#, Java, Haskell, Rust, R, MATLAB, etc. - anything that uses the hardware-supported floating-point - will _all_ have the exact same behaviours.  Your suggested solution isn't a good one - it happens to work for this particular example, but will fail in other cases (try `t2 = 0.57`). (BTW, `t1` is undefined in your code snippet.)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work as expected because checking floats for equality almost never works as expected.  A quick fix would be to use `math.isclose`.  This allows you to adjust your tolerance as well.  Remember that when doing arithmetic mod r, r is equivalent to 0, so you should check if you're close to 0 or r.

```
import math

t1 = 0.02
factor = 0.01
res = t1 % factor
print(math.isclose(res, 0) or math.isclose(res, factor))
```

This is pretty quick and dirty and you will want to make sure your tolerances are working correctly and equivalently for both of those checks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the decimal module. The decimal module provides support for fast correctly-rounded decimal floating point arithmetic.

```
import decimal
print( decimal.Decimal('0.03') % decimal.Decimal('0.01') == decimal.Decimal('0') )
```

Gives :

```
True
```